# Enabling XSendFile causes 404 for images on Wordpress Multisite / Network

Tags: php, htaccess, wp-filesystem

I've compiled and installed the `XSendFile` module and added the following lines to my `.htaccess`:

```
XSendFile On
```

It shows up as being activated in `<?php info() ?>` under loaded modules.

The problem is, when I activate it in my site's top level wp-config.php using:

```
define('WPMU_SENDFILE', true);
```

All images on all the blogs in our network stop loading. When you try and click on them you get a 404 error for `wp-includes/ms-files.php`

I figure this is something to do with my `.htaccess` not magicing the URLs correctly, but it looks correct to me:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

# uploaded files
RewriteRule ^files/(.+) wp-includes/ms-files.php?file=$1 [L]

# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
RewriteRule ^wp-admin$ wp-admin/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $1 [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*\.php)$ $1 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]

XSendFile On
```

How can I get XSendFile to correctly send files on our Wordpress Network?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It wasn't a .htaccess problem, but an apache configuration problem.

On a Mac server you need to:

- compile XSendFile as a universal binary: `apxs -cia -Wc,"-arch i386 -arch x86_64" -Wl,"-arch i386 -arch x86_64" mod_xsendfile.c` and
- modify the site specific httpd.conf file in `/Library/Server/Web/Config/apache2/sites`.

If you're having the same problem, [I wrote about this on my blog](http://topstoreyapps.com/blog/2013/12/22/xsendfile-and-hosting-wordpress-on-a-mac-server) - hopefully it's helpful to someone!